What ultimately happened to the Urim Vetumim?
What ultimately happened to the Urim Vetumim?
Will we need it when Moshiach arrives?
Was it hidden with the Ark?
Will we just make a new one?

Only priests could work the oracle. [Deut. 33:8] After King David's reign, the Urim no longer gave answers and were replaced by the prophets.  The Bible says that difficult decisions will have to wait...

...until a priest with Urim and Tummim should appear. [Ezra 2:63]

The Talmud is more explicit:

From the time when the early prophets died, [the Urim and Tummim stopped giving answers]... Rav Naḥman said: In the days of David sometimes an answer rose up and sometimes not. For example, Tzadok [a High Priest] asked and an answer rose up for him, whereas Abiathar [another High Priest] asked and an answer did not rise up for him [2 Samuel 15:24].
[Sotah 48b]

The Talmud adds that King Ahashverosh, in the story of Purim, wore the priestly vestments of the Urim from the plundered First Temple. [Megillah 12a]

So would that imply they are still in Iran or any sources that say or imply they were brought back to eretz yisroel?

See Were the אוּרִ֥ים Urim & תֻמִּֽים Thummim ever returned (after the Babylonian exile) to fulfill Ezra 2:63? https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/63578/were-the-%D7%90%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%A8%D6%B4%D6%A5%D7%99%D7%9D-urim-%D7%AA%D6%BB%D7%9E%D6%BC%D6%B4%D6%BD%D7%99%D7%9D-thummim-ever-returned-after-the-babylonian-ex

I was told on excellent authority that they are in Western Africa. Sort of.

(It may be necessary to go through a few more "hoops" upon arriving in WA.)
